# Inkscape PDF to SVG conversion issue with text

Tags: pdf, svg, type-conversion, inkscape

I am running this inkscape command on Ubuntu:

inkscape -z -f input.pdf -l output.svg

to export [this PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4XyPrRIBSAleFVaekNIb3dOWkU) (input.pdf) as an SVG (output.svg). There seems to be an issue with letter case for some of the text. For examples, "SPECIFICATION" in PDF becomes "SpecIfIcatIon" in SVG, "PROFILES" becomes "ProfILeS" etc.

Any ideas why this is happening?

P.S I've seen "Inaccurate pdf to text conversion" question but that's not my case as the text copies correcrtly when doing copy paste.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm having trouble with the same issue..